# Partial class with portable class library

Tags: c#, partial-classes, portable-class-library

I have ported a class library to Portable Class Library, this Portable class library is shared between the server code, WPF applications and Silverlight, so far so good

Before porting I had a partial class in the Silverlight project to support custom properties only relevant in that application, but now I am unable to create partial class with properties.

If I do VS only picks up the properties defined in the partial class and not in the portable class.

So the question is: Is it possible to use Partial classes with Portable class library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot extend a class from a different assembly. Partial classes only work for multiple fragments of a single class *in the assembly being built*. It sounds like the class is now in a separate dll: you can't extend that via partial classes.

Maybe encapsulate the class instead.

Comment: ahhh of course why didn't i think about that, this project was created without mvvm, so am probably going to convert a part of it to mvvm and create a VM that can hold the custom properties